# Copying and Pasting data from one workbook to another resulting in random cells getting data/empty rows not getting pasted data

Tags: excel, vba, macos, copy-paste

***UPDATE***

Half of my issue is resolved now but I am still having issues. The majority of the data I am pasting to the new workbook is working fine. If you press the button several times, the data gets pasted to the next available row. However, three rows in particular are not working. The data will be pasted in the right place the first time you press the macro button but then the data will be pasted 31 rows down from the appropriate row. I am completely confused by this. Is it some sort of formatting issues with the cells in that part of the worksheet? Any help would be appreciated.

***Original Problem***

Let me explain whats going on. I am trying to make it so that once a form has been filled out in one workbook, the user presses a button and the data from that form is copied and pasted to another workbook that acts like a master file for all the data. The data from the form is supposed to be pasted in specific columns in the second workbook.

So far I have been successful in creating crude but working code that accomplishes this but now I am running into some issues. When I press the button on the first workbook, everything gets pasted as intended but a cell (G163 specifically) will get pasted with data. I checked and nothing in the code is making the macro paste to that cell specifically. Also, if I press the button a second time, some cells will not paste in the next available empty cell but instead will be pushed down the column and get pasted in a different cell than intended.

I am very new to excel vba so any help would be greatly appreciated. I will post my code below and some pictures of the odd pasting as well.

```
Sub Button1099_Click()

If IsEmpty(Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("A42")) = True Then
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("A4").Copy
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("A42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Else
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("A4").Copy
Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If

If IsEmpty(Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("B42")) = True Then
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("P2").Copy
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("B42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Else
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("P2").Copy
Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If

If IsEmpty(Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("C42")) = True Then
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("P3").Copy
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("C42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Else
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("P3").Copy
Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If

If IsEmpty(Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("D42")) = True Then
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("C10").Copy
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("D42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Else
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("C10").Copy
Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If

If IsEmpty(Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("E42")) = True Then
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("C9").Copy
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("E42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Else
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("C9").Copy
Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If

If IsEmpty(Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("F42")) = True Then
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("C11").Copy
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("F42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Else
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("C11").Copy
Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If

If IsEmpty(Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("G42")) = True Then
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("B17").Copy
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("G42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Else
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("B17").Copy
Range("G" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("G" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If

If IsEmpty(Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("H42")) = True Then
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("C12").Copy
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("H42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Else
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("C12").Copy
Range("H" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("H" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If

If IsEmpty(Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("I42")) = True Then
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("J10").Copy
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("I42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Else
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("J10").Copy
Range("I" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("I" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If

If IsEmpty(Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("J42")) = True Then
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("J11").Copy
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("J42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Else
Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Range("J11").Copy
Range("J" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7").Range("J" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If

 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Save

End Sub
```

This is what the second workbook looks like once you click the button once:

[Pasted workbook after one button press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1iEC.png)

[Pasted workbook after one button press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRII5.png)

This is what the workbook looks like if you press the button again:

[Pasted workbook after two button presses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETCTk.png)

[Pasted workbook after two button presses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtQu0.png)

Comment: you need to identify the workbook that you are selecting the first empty cell. I would set up a variable(s) for the first empty cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are copying cell to cell, try this;

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Workbooks("Formtest.xlsm").Worksheets("Form")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7")

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If ws2.Range("A42").Value = "" Then
    ws2.Range("A42").Value = ws1.Range("A4").Value
Else: ws2.Range("A" & lRow).Offset(1).Value = ws1.Range("A4").Value
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried out your code but I keep getting a subscript out of range error for Set ws2 = Workbooks("2018Monthly.xls").Worksheets("7")

Comment: Is your workbook opened? your code implies that it is already open. If the workbook is not opened you will get the error. If you want the code to open the workbook, the you will need to use `Workbooks.Open` command.

Comment: whoops I accidentally deleted that command when I was trying out your code. It works now! I'm in the process of adding it to the rest of the macro. Ill update this if I get any other issues.